# How to create an exclusion list in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I just wanted to create a data extension and mark it as a exclusion list. Appreciate if anyone can mention the steps for that since I'm new to marketing cloud.

Thanks,
Prasad

Comment: In short, any sendable DE can be used as an exclusion DE. Just while deploying add it under the Excluded section instead of Targeted as in the below image shared by Mr. Duc Le

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the definition for [Exclusion Lists in Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_exclusion_list.htm&type=5)

> An exclusion list is any list, group, or data extension you create in the application that at the time of send you select to exclude from the send. If your Email Studio account has subscriber key enabled, the system excludes using the subscriber key value. If your account does not have subscriber key enabled, the system excludes using email address.

So it can be a data extension. To be clear, it has to be a sendable data extension hence MC system can be based on the related field on Subscriber Key in that DE and exclude these subscribers from the send DE source.

For example: when you do the [send flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_send_flow.htm&type=5): Email Studio >> Content >> Select an email and click send

At the Select Audience step, you can drag and drop your exclusion data extension there

[image]